# Rails has many_though relationship with same class and join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I want to build a relationship between `two users`, through `chats`. A `Chat` has an `invitee` and a `participant`, which both are of type `User`.

Assuming the `Schema` and `Chat` model in my example are correct, I'm missing the `relationships` inside the `User` model. This is where I've tried many things but always ended up getting errors. Basically what I want to achieve is from a user perspective is this:

`User.first.chats # => returning all chats which are referencing the user as either invitee or participant`.
Basically this should return the same as the `chats` method in the User model.

I guess there should be two relationships in the `User` model:

```
class User
  has_many :chats
  has_many :chatpartners, through: :chats
end
```

Those don't work, though. I guess the problem is that I'm using the `User` model twice. Two other solutions which didn't work as well (probably wrong in more than one point):

```
class User
  has_many :chats, ->(id) { where("invitee_id = ? OR participant_id = ?", id, id) }

  has_and_belongs_to_many :chatpartners,
                      class_name: "User",
                      join_table: "chats",
                      foreign_key: :invitee_id,
                      association_foreign_key: :participant_id
end
```

I guess if I get these relationships right, things like these will work automatically:

`Chat.first.invitee # => returning the User referenced by invitee_id`

`Chat.first.participant # => returning the User referenced by participant_id`

`User.first.chats.users # => returning the users referenced by the chat`

**This is what I have so far:**

**User model**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  def chats
    Chat.where("invitee_id = ? OR participant_id = ?", id, id)
  end
end
```

**Chat model**

```
class Chat < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :invitee, foreign_key: :invitee_id, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :participant, foreign_key: :participant_id, class_name: "User"
end
```

**Schema**

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20170311085652) do
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "chats", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "invitee_id"
    t.integer  "participant_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",     null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",     null: false
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at",                null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                null: false
  end
end
```

Please let me know if I forgot to mention anything or something doesn't make sense. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be set up `User` like this:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # same as the method you have now
  def chats
    Chat.where("invitee_id = ? OR participant_id = ?", id, id)
  end

  def chat_partners
    User.where(id: chats.pluck(:invitee_id, :participant_id).flatten.uniq.reject { |i| i == self.id })
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but then I get this error: `Association named 'chats' was not found on User; perhaps you misspelled it?`

Comment: @Linus: I'm using the `chats` method that you already have defined in your question! :-)

Comment: To further clarify - it's the one under the "This is what I have so far:" title, not the `has_many :chats` that you mention you tried

Comment: Of course, sorry if I was a bit unclear :) What I meant was that I think I at least need one relationship in that model. But still thanks.

Comment: I've updated the code example for clarity. The tricky thing here is that it's not just about associations, but also the specific logic you need i.e. you want all users that *aren't the current user*, but which can *either be invitees or participants*. This code should at least let you pull out those users, and return an `ActiveRecord::Relation` that can support further chaining